# How to show tooltip on disabled Button in Angular without wrapping button tag in div tag with tippy tooltip?

Tags: angular, angular7

tippyTooltip is directive which uses tippy.js tooltip
`<button [disabled]="true" tippyTooltip ></button>`

Comment: Welcome to SO Modi Sahab, Post your minimum code here or a workable fiddle, NOone will code for you, show what you have done so far , and we will try to give you a possible workaround or solution

Answer (score 0):

A normal tooltip can be achieved by using title attribute like below :-

```
<button [title]="'My ToolTip'"> My Button </button>
```